# Making a Content Type the subpage of a Views page for the sake of Breadcrumbs

Tags: views

I have a Content Type named Cars and a Views page which lists all those cars. Is it possible to put the Cars content type under The Views page so my breadcrumbs would come out as `Home > Cars > Sample Car`. **Cars** is the Views page, **Sample Car** is the Content Type.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way.... Using Custom module.

```
function hook_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode){
  if($view_mode == 'full' && $node->type =='cars'){
    $bc[] = l('Home', '<front>');
    $bc[] = l('Cars', url('cars'))
    $bc[] = l($node->title, url('node/'. $node->nid));

    drupal_set_breadcrumb($bc);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try.

Comment: I pasted it in my module and it still showed the default breadcrumbs. Am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 0):

For this you will have to use [Menu Breadcrumb](http://drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb) and Path module

Define your view's path as `cars` and define path for your Cars type nodes as `cars/sample-car`

Menu Breadcrumb will do the magic for you to arrange hierarchy of your view and nodes in bread crumb

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the Menu Breadcrumb module? There's no D7 version yet and the dev module seems buggy.

Answer (score 0):

The [Menu Position module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_position) should allow you to do this, and it works for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Crumbs](http://drupal.org/project/crumbs) module (7.x-1.2 +).
Go to Admin > Structure > Crumbs > Node parent,
here you can configure a parent path for each node type, with token support.